# Better way to insert elements into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array and I have a list of elements I want to insert at specific locations (not contiguous) into that array. The indices are in another numpy array.

```
target answer: [1,2,3,4,5]
original array: [1,3,5]
elements to insert: [2,4]
indices: [1,3]
```

`numpy.insert(arr,[1,3],[2,4])` dosen't give the desired result. It gives `[1,2,3,5,4]`.
Any pointers?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this. It's more efficient to work with Python lists if they're changing size

Comment: The complication is with your choice of indices - are they relative to the original array or the target.  `insert` put the `2` after `original[1]`, and `4` after `original[3]`.  You in contrast want them to be at the `result[1]` and `result[3]` slots.

Comment: @roganjosh, normally multiple insertions into a list require starting with the last, so that growth of the list doesn't mess up the indexing.  In this case, that iteration can start from the first, because `indices` already factors in the growth.

Comment: @hpaulj I think you're right. I've been trying to benchmark in chat and it's not as horrendous as I believed for arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use range-offsetted indices with `np.insert` -

```
np.insert(a, add_idx - np.arange(len(add_idx)), add_val)
```

Sample run -

```
In [20]: a
Out[20]: array([1, 3, 5])

In [21]: add_idx
Out[21]: [1, 3]

In [22]: add_val
Out[22]: [2, 4]

In [23]: np.insert(a, add_idx - np.arange(len(add_idx)), add_val)
Out[23]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: This is perfect. I tried to trace this on the paper but I am not quite intuitively clear how this works and how you came up with this. Could you explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The list approach is:

```
In [122]: alist=[1,3,5]
In [123]: for i,j in zip([1,3],[2,4]):
     ...:     alist[i:i] = [j]
     ...:     
In [124]: alist
Out[124]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`np.insert` is a complex function taking different approaches depending on the indices input.  But in a case like this is uses a boolean mask approach:

```
In [126]: arr = np.array([1,3,5])
In [127]: res = np.zeros(5, int) # 5 is len(arr)+len([2,4])
In [128]: mask = res.astype(bool)
In [129]: mask[[1,3]] = True
In [130]: mask
Out[130]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False])
In [131]: res[mask] = [2,4]
In [132]: res[~mask] = arr
In [133]: res
Out[133]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

`mask` defines where the new values are supposed to go, and `~mask` where the originals go.

`insert` assumes the indices are given relative to the source array, not the target.  To do this same thing, it has to be given `[1,2]`, in other words after `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`.  `insert` would adjust `[1,2]` to `[1,3]` to use the above masking approach.  @Divakar's answer takes your `[1,3]` and converts it to the `[1,2]` that `insert` expects.  He in effect is compensating for the offset that `insert` normally adds.

---

If we used `[1,2]` (indices relative to the source list), the list iteration that I used above is wrong.  It doesn't account for the fact that the list grows after inserting the `2`:

```
In [134]: alist=[1,3,5]
In [135]: for i,j in zip([1,2],[2,4]):
     ...:     alist[i:i] = [j]   
In [136]: alist
Out[136]: [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

To compensate for that, a common trick is to insert in reverse order:

```
In [137]: alist=[1,3,5]
In [138]: for i,j in zip([1,2][::-1],[2,4][::-1]):
     ...:     alist[i:i] = [j]
In [139]: alist
Out[139]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```